# Unique instance of a Yammer conversation per Sharepoint list item

Tags: yammer

I'm fairly new to Sharepoint Online and Yammer. I have a Yammer Enterprise network that has been activated, and I have a corresponding Sharepoint Online site (Office 365).

I'm using Sharepoint's default Contacts List as a simple CRM system. What I'd like to do is to embed a unique instance of a Yammer thread into each Conacts List item. For example, item Customer1 would have its own Yammer thread, as would item Customer2 and so on. Currenty, when I try to embed a Yammer thread, the same conversation shows up across all list items in the same list. How do I change this to make each item's conversation thread unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a field to your list that holds the Yammer message ID, and use that in your Yammer embed to display the appropriate thread.

You need to create the conversation, though, before you can obtain that ID. You can either do that manually or via a Remote Event Receiver using a Yammer App auth token and the Yammer REST API.

Comment: So the Yammer embed code allows me to reference a field as a variable? Also, would you kindly provide some further pointers on how to set up the Remote Event Receiver?

Comment: The embed is JavaScript, so yeah, you can use variables. https://developer.yammer.com/docs/embed

Comment: I do see an option to specify feed id but I don't see an option to specify message id in the embed code.