# AutoPost SharePoint list values as a Yammer comment

Tags: sharepoint-online, yammer, yammer-embed

I have a requirement where I have a SharePoint List with column say **MYComment**.

Whenever the value in MYComment is modified, I would like to have this value as a comment on one of My Yammer Group . The Yammer group integration with Sharepoint list values is something I am looking forward to.

Any help or any direction to get me started is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can use REST API to update comment in group. There is always `PreSaveAction` method which you can use to call the method to update comment in your yammer group.

Comment: check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164851/unique-instance-of-a-yammer-conversation-per-sharepoint-list-item

Comment: I suppose you can also have a workflow that emails it to a Yammer group.

Comment: IS it? a workflow? Please elaborate if that is possible. guess that will be the simplest approach

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options here, like a SharePoint Webhook or a remote event receiver. I've done what you're looking for using a Remote Event Receiver and the Yammer REST APIs (called from C#) but now that [Flow](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?q=yammer) is out I'd recommend you look there first. Here's a flow template that posts to Yammer whenever a list item is created in a list.

https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/fb2dca30b6304272965e20a31125ff0c/when-a-new-item-is-created-in-sharepoint-post-to-my-yammer/